# Crop background image then resize to fit specific dimensions CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I have been approaching this problem for a couple of hours now and have yet to find a solution that works.  I have url for an image of dimensions (1060px x 650px), this image needs to be a background image for an element.  However I need 200px cropped off the right, bottom, and left sides.  I then need this image resized to fit back into the original 1060px x 650px size.  Both

```
Background-alignment: fixed;
Background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Must both be used and the background image should not be resized if the screen is resized.  Any help, direction, or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

You can use background-size property in css.

Comment: If someone giving down votes, please explain the reason.